# Multi-JOIN - Have separate columns which reference same table, but have different values

Tags: mysql, sql

Schema in question: (Note: Unrelated stuff removed from img.)

[image]

Is it possible to make select that would print:

```
SELECT
A.name 'account name',
D.name 'deck name owned by account',
T.name 'type name of the DECK',
C.name 'card name contained in deck',
T.name 'type name of the CARD'
FROM account A
JOIN deck D ON A.id=D.owner
JOIN deck_card DC ON D.id=DC.deck
JOIN card C ON DC.card=C.id
JOIN `type` T ON C.`type`=T.id
```

I problem is in `T.name` part (both deck and card can have types, but also have different values).

Comment: Btw. Feel free to give this thread proper title (if such exists) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join the `type` table one more time and this time with `deck` table.

Try this:

```
SELECT
A.name 'account name',
D.name 'deck name owned by account',
T2.name 'type name of the DECK',
C.name 'card name contained in deck',
T.name 'type name of the CARD'
FROM account A
JOIN deck D ON A.id=D.owner
JOIN deck_card DC ON D.id=DC.deck
JOIN card C ON DC.card=C.id
JOIN `type` T ON C.`type`=T.id
JOIN `type` T2 ON D.`type`=T2.id
```

Comment: There were bells ringing, but in different church. :P